# counting multiple instances of a char (in a row) in a string

Tags: java, loops, iteration, counter

No idea why my code isn't working. It keeps returning a value of 1 instead of what I expect.

```
public class Lab5Example
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  System.out.println(longestRun("aabbbccd"));
  System.out.println("Expected 3");
  System.out.println(longestRun("aaa"));
  System.out.println("Expected 3");
  System.out.println(longestRun("aabbbb"));
  System.out.println("Expected 4");
  }


public static int longestRun(String s)
{
int count = 1;
int max = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i += 1) {
  char c = s.charAt(i);
  char current = s.charAt(i + 1);
  if (c == current) {
    count += 1;
  }
  else {
    if (count > max) {
      count = max;
    }
    current = c;       
  }
}
return max;
}  
}
```

Debugger isn't working right so I have no idea what's not working.

Comment: Why do you think the debugger isn't working?

Comment: You initialize `max` as `1`, never modify it, and then return it; it couldn't return anything other than `1`.

Comment: Looks like a combination of not setting `max` correctly (at all), and also `count` needs to be reset at some point otherwise you're counting all duplicate chars in a row instead of counting the longest sequence of a given char in a row.

Comment: @ScottHunter I hit something (an option or whatever) and I checked eveything, but no matter what, once I hit Debug (for any code I'v written), it doesn't allow me to go through the steps.

@resueman yea I caught that, turned `count = max` to `max = count`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 3 issues.

`max = count` should be `count = max`. This is so you store the highest score found thus far.

`current = c` should be `count = 1`. This is so you reset the count to start the counting over on the next char sequence.

Outside of your loop you need to do a final check to see if the last char sequence had the highest score. `if(count > max) max = count;`

This would all look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i += 1) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    char current = s.charAt(i + 1);
    if (c == current) {
        count += 1;
    }
    else {
        if (count > max) {
            max = count; // #1
        }
        count = 1; // #2
    }
}
if(count > max) // #3
    max = count;

return max;
```

Comment: Yea I caught the `count = max` bs right after I posted haha, but I completely forgot about the reset. Definitely need to get my debugger figured out again. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: No problem glad to help. The `current = c` isn't needed since the chars will be set on the next loop iteration.

Answer (score 2):

You want this:

```
if (count > max) {
  max = count;
}
```

Instead of:

```
if (count > max) {
  count = max;
}
```

Then at the end before you return add this:

```
if(count > max)
{
    max = count;
}
return max;
```

Comment: Even then, this still only works if the longest run isn't at the end of the string. `max` will only get set when a new letter is found. Also `count` won't be reset now.

Comment: Who downvoted? At least say why when you downvote...If you don't then how is the downvote helping the poster?...

Comment: Regarding the edit, I would argue `if (max == 1)` should be another `if (count > max)`, just in case it's a longer string with multiple runs. DV wasn't me btw

Comment: @jonhopkins yes your right...